# Variance of bivariate values

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, bivariate

If I have two lines of regression ($y$ on $x$ and $x$ on $y$) and I know $\sigma(x)$, why isn't the variance of $y$ equal to $m^2 \sigma(x)^2$ where $m$ is the slope?

Comment: Those two regression lines would have different slopes so you would have two different models, with two different slopes - could you clarify your question?

Comment: I can't tell, that's all I've got. I assume I just pick one of the lines, but is my equation for the variance of $y$ correct?

Comment: Is it a homework? If so, it should be tagged as `[self-study]`, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a linear model

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot x + \epsilon,$$

the following is true about the variance of the dependent variable $y$:

$$\mathrm{var}(y) = \beta_1^2 \cdot \mathrm{var}(x) + \mathrm{var}(\epsilon).$$

---

Your assumption is limited to cases where $\mathrm{var}(\epsilon) = 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure what $\epsilon$ is. If I have two regression lines and nothing else, is my $\epsilon = 0$?

Comment: @user51819 $\epsilon$ respresents the residuals. These are the deviations of the individuals points from the regression line.

Comment: I don't have individual points, just the two lines of regression and $\sigma(x)$

Comment: @user51819 In this case, you can't calculate $\mathrm{var}(y)$ based on the slope and $\mathrm{var}(x)$.